# Mask overlay with matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have the following code which shows an image called `zero`.

I would like just to overlay a mask image (only `0` and `1` values) of the same dimensions so that `0` values are transparent (and then we can see the values of the `zero` image) and `1` values are shown in black.

What could I do?

```
hFig = figure(1);    
set(hFig, 'Position', [11 11 27 7.5]);    
set( gca, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.05 0.05 0.93 1.2] );    
set(0,'defaultFigureUnits','centimeters');    
m_proj('equidistant cylindrical','longitudes',[-15 21],'latitudes',[11.5 18]);    
m_gridF('ytick',4,'tickdir','out','ticklen',0.005,'linestyle','none');

hold; Plat=18-[0:13]*0.5;    
Plon=-15+[0:72]*0.5;    
[Plg,Plt]=meshgrid(Plon,Plat);    
m_pcolor(Plg,Plt,zero);shading flat;

hold on;    
polarmap(flipud(polarmap),0)    
M=m_shaperead('clip');

for k=1:length(M.ncst),    
    m_line(M.ncst{k}(:,1),M.ncst{k}(:,2),'color','k'); 
end    
hold;

h=colorbar('SouthOutside');    
set(h, 'Position', [0.13 .1 .78 .05]);    
set(get(h,'title'),'string','test','fontsize',14)    
hold;
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate code formatting when asking.

Comment: You're using **a lot** of functions that we don't have access to.  What exactly is this code doing?